# Images have white space

Tags: magento-2.1, image

I'm having some troubles with product images in Magento.

**I'm using Porto theme, in homepage I have a 4-featured-items grid (2x2). I want images to be 610x360px but I'm not able to do this. Instead I have images with white space.**

Strange is, if I open the inspector and find the img url, open it in browser and I see that images have white border (added by Magento?). Can't figure it out.

I'm new in Magento, it is pretty urgent.

You can see the issue here: **mobiroloshop.com** (got same problem with all images in website)

Comment: Paste your template file code which is responsible for displaying your images

Comment: You mean theme/etc/view.xml?

Comment: @Nidheesh You mean this?

Comment: @GiuseppeCapoluongo, Everything is fine now right?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara, yeah just add a new <image (your id)> in etc/view.xml then edit you .phtml file giving the image that new id.

Comment: @GiuseppeCapoluongo, where should i add?

Answer (score 3):

In `<vendor>/<theme>/etc/view.xml` you should be able to adjust the settings of the image to remove the frame, like this:

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>610</width>
    <height>360</height>
    <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```

***However***, there is an open issue where setting `<frame>` to false returns true. [See this Github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4622).

There is also a fix in the Github comments:

> After creating a plugin to convert the string value to an integer (which
>   properly casts to a boolean), the image frame is not added.
>
> ```
> public function beforeSetKeepFrame($image, $keep)
> {
>     if (is_string($keep)) {
>         $keep = (strtolower($keep) === 'true') ? 1 : 0;
>     }
>     return [$keep];
> }
> ```

Comment: still adds a frame in 2.1.12

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix is to figure out what the dimensions should be, if it gets whitespace above/below then the height is too much otherwise if it's to the left/right then it's too narrow so increase the width. In the already mentioned:

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>610</width>
    <height>360</height>
</image>
```