# Magento 2 adding white border to images

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

On product page im getting white border on top and bottom of my product images.

Reading the [doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html) and some other questions [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169605/remove-white-background-from-thumbnail-images-in-magento-2-1-3) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144449/images-have-white-space), i think this should be the solution:

*theme_dir/etc/view.xml:*

```
<image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
    <width>700</width>
    <height>700</height>
    <aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio>
    <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```

While changing `width` and `height` does exactly what to be expected, `frame` does exactly nothing.

Magento 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to set image sizes according to the aspect ratio of images in `view.xml` file inside your theme

Code would be like this:

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
                <width>200</width>
                <height>248</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>165</width>
                <height>165</height>
            </image>
            ........
        </images>
    </media>
    ......
</view>
```

The only reason that Magento show white border on images because it's width and height is not set according to the aspect ratio of images

Also, set this in all type of images:

```
<aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio>
<frame>false</frame>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: The uploaded images have different aspect ratios.

Comment: then `<frame>false</frame>` is best approach for your, make sure you copy it to all images blocks

Comment: As stated above, `frame` does not have any affect. I can't see why editing all the other image blocks could help. Tried it - it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Please set "aspect_ratio" and "frame" to "false"

```
<image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
    <width>700</width>
    <height>700</height>
    <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
    <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```

Comment: using `frame` requires `aspect_ratio` to be `true`. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html . Tried nevertheless. Had no effect